# Could not run react-native app android. Getting syntax error in the metro bundler which are related to react-native-wheel-picker

Tags: android, react-native

I have been trying to run a react native app on my windows laptop. Whenever I use `npx react-native run-android` I am getting some syntax error as shown below which suggests some error in react-native-wheel-picker package. I tried to debug my going through the library documentation, but everything looks fine. Can anyone help me through this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try Deleting the node_modules folder and npm install

Comment: I did many times. Still the issue is same :(

Comment: Try to clean npm cache

Comment: Tried but didn't work. Is this because of some dependency packages?

Comment: Check the solution I posted below, which worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some digging into it a bit and compared the old code which is working and new setup which I am trying to do with `npm install` and I compared the `package-lock.json` files of both. It is **the culprit**.

In the old one there are some inter dependencies of prop-types which are not properly installed with new setup using `npm install`. So, I copied the old `package-lock.json` and did the package installation and it worked like a charm :)

[image]